# Jquery finding element within index of each

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to trigger a click on an element by sniffing out if a sibling contains an invalid input. I tried to do the following

- Get a list of elements
- Within that list, find cases where sibling contains an element
- Trigger a click based on that

Totally stumped. I appreciate any help.

Here's my non-working code.

```js
// If page has invalid inputs
if ($('input:invalid').length) {

  // Look through all list items only if it isn't already open
  $('.collapsible > li').children('.collapsible-header:not(.active)').each(function(i, header) {

    // Within each, make sure siblings collapsible body doesn't have bad inputs
    if ($(i).index().siblings('.collapsible-body').has('input:invalid').length) {

      // this does nothing
      $(this).siblings('.collapsible-header').trigger('click');

    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><input type="text" class="validate invalid" id="contact" name="contact" value="" required></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hard to answer from just non-working javascript. Need to see HTML examples that demonstrate what should and what should not be selected.

Comment: this looks kind suspicious - $(i)...you are looking in the whole dom with just passing in a 0, 1, 2

Comment: What script do you use for the collapsing? Is there a method for collapsing/expanding the tabs? Wouldn't it be easier, more readable to call such method rather than achieving that by triggering click?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm a total newb at jQuery. The answer below has it close. Thanks for jumping in.

Comment: You are getting an error message with your code. Next time ***include*** any error messages you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you want to :

- select all inactive `.collapsible-header` elements
- filter out any that have sibling `.collapsible-body` elements containing invalid inputs
- trigger 'click' on any `.collapsible-header` elements that remain after filtering.

If so, try the following jQuery :

```
$('.collapsible > li').children('.collapsible-header:not(.active)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).siblings('.collapsible-body').find('input:invalid').length;
}).trigger('click');
```

Comment: This is super close. I added example HTML above. I want the closed collapsible with the invalid input to open. My test showed it opens the one before.

Comment: It ended up not needing anything after length. Thank you for your help! I was waaaaay off.

Comment: Aha, I understand. The heart of this solution lies in exploiting `.filter()` to leave just the inactive collapsible-headers that you are interested in. Your `.each()` approach wasn't exactly way off. It could be made to work but arguably not as cleanly.